# Should SAML 2.0 protocol be used for desktop application single sign on?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, identity, saml-2.0

I'm trying to implement SSO for a desktop application, and I'm currently doing research on what's the best tool to use. I came across SAML, but from my understanding SAML is really meant for web applications. Is there a way to use the SAML protocol for a desktop app?

Example use case: user logs into machine, and when he or she clicks on the app icon, they are automatically signed in.

Answer (score 2):

Your example use case is IWA - Integrated windows auth - which is a browser function rather than a protocol function. It typically happens only on domain joined PC's.

SAML relies on redirects so if you want to do this via SAML you need to add some kind of browser pop-up.

You could use OpenID Connect - far more lightweight - built on REST - or the WS-Fed active profile i.e. WCF rather than http browser functionality.

Comment: Hmm, from my understanding I shouldn't need a browser. Please take a look at my comment for @chenrui 's answer below for a more explicit example of what i'm looking for.

Comment: IWA relies on Kerberos tokens. That has nothing whatsoever to do with SAML. If you don't want a browser you have to handle the HTTP redirects yourself and display the login form etc. IWA is not true SSO. True SSO requires an Identity provider like ADFS.

Comment: I think your question is more "IWA via desktop application". This may help: https://www.quora.com/How-would-SAML-authentication-work-on-a-Windows-desktop-when-using-a-Windows-based-application

Comment: Hello @RobertJefferies, did you solve the problem? I have similar kind of requirement and stuck at the same place as you were/are. Can you please tell me how you resolved the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Before going for `SAML 2.0`, `OpenID Connect`, you may want to ask why do you need `Single Sign On`.

The reason why we have single sign on is that we want to separate out `Identity Provider` (or `OpenID Provider`) and `Service Provider` (`Relaying Party`). Furthermore, it can be multiplexed in between, that is how identity federation happens.

Of cause, the session setup are through server-to-server communications. But when it comes to `Single Logout`, it does involve with either `front-channel` (`UI-to-server`) communications or `back-channel` (`server-to-server`) communication.

Now comes into your question:

1. I think you can use `SAML 2.0` to exchange the identity, but it is just too heavyweight to do it. `SAML 2.0` has been widely used in the industry and that is why many people are still using it.
2. The newer SSO technology is `OpenID Connect`, which is identity layer on top of `OAuth 2.0`, you may want to take a look at it. [OpenID Connect FAQ](http://openid.net/connect/faq/)
3. But ultimately, your UI (web or mobile or desktop) are just checking against either a session or an identity store through backend service calls. And how backend authenticates the user purely depends on the implementation. Don't mix `client` with `server`.

Comment: Perhaps a more concrete example may help clarify the functionality i'm looking for. When you login to your windows machine, and you click on microsoft outlook (the desktop application), you dont have to enter your outlook credentials. This is what i'm looking for.